# jQuery matching a single class against predefined list where element has multiple classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I am trying to figure out if there is a way around doing `.hasClass()` multiple times to see if the active element I am working with has one of currently four specific classes, I am also trying to figure out the most optimized way to do this while the element(s) that are acting as the trigger (or the active element) has multiple classes in it mostly for styling purposes.

Example of the HTML:

```
<div class="form_row">
    <div class="primary_row">1</div>
</div>
<div class="form_row">
    <div class="primary_row subexists">1</div>
    <div class="primary_row_sub">1a</div>
</div>
<div class="form_row">
    <div class="primary_row subexists">1</div>
    <div class="primary_row_sub subexists">1a</div>
    <div class="secondary_row">2</div>
</div>
<div class="form_row">
    <div class="primary_row subexists">1</div>
    <div class="primary_row_sub subexists">1a</div>
    <div class="secondary_row subexists">2</div>
    <div class="secondary_row_sub">2a</div>
</div>
```

I am in the progress of currently building it up, so this is still a rough draft, but its safe to assume more classes will exist on various elements per the need. The Four main classes I am worried about are `primary_row, primary_row_sub, secondary_row, secondary_row_sub`. I am building a click handler like:

```
$('.form_row > div').click(function()
{
   //code
});
```

in this click handler I want to be able to detect if the element clicked is one of the four mentioned above. Where if it is, I want to do something based on which. So determining which class is of the element clicked, rather than building four click handlers one for each type. I am hoping I can keep it optimized and contained to a single handler. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just add one more class to all those elements, and identify that one class instead?

Comment: @Blazemonger That suffers from the same problem in my comment on your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option:

```
var classMap = {"one": function () { alert("one");}, 
                "two": function () { alert("two");},
                "three": function () { alert("three");} 
               }
,   classes = "";

$('div').click(function (e) {
    classes = this.className.split(" ");
    for (key in classMap) {
        if ($.inArray(key, classes) !== -1) {
            classMap[key]();
        }   
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wp9X7/5/

Comment: You know, I was actually thinking something similar.. I just couldn't picture firing off the functionality from the idea. I can pass parameters using a function call like that right? Also should I do a `typeof == 'function'` or something just to be safe?

Comment: I just made a working demo. Yes, you can pass parameters. I'll try to add some more substance.

Comment: Well, this definitely gets me started, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($(this).is(".primary_row")) {
    ...
} elseif ($(this).is(".primary_row_sub")) {
    ...
} and so on
```

Comment: Not really any better than using `.hasClass`, is it?

Comment: @Blazemonger Right. But it's a few characters shorter. :)

Comment: `.is` is much slower than `.hasClass`. ("Much" being unnoticable, because browsers are fast, but still.)